# How do i get the url to my resources?

Tags: java, url, path

I noticed that when I try to load a resource (an image, data, sound file, ect.) it is not possible to put it in the same file as the source code and just type "soundfiles/sound.wav". What is the best way to get this url?

Specifically here:

```
// load wave data from buffer
WaveData wavefile = WaveData.create("spaceinvaders/" + path);
```

I have done this before in many different ways, just wondering what the best way is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ship your application in jar it's common way to package resources also in jar and access them using classloader:

```
//jar structure
your.jar
|--com
|  `--... //classes here
`--resources
   `--spaceinvaders
      `--sound.wav
```

And code to access:

```
InputStream resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/spaceinvaders/sound.wav");
```

Comment: @StevenRogers, try it. It should work. By the way, check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html

Comment: This is not working. I am using LWJGL right now and i have to set the class path to the lwjgl jar libraries for it to even run. So when i 'getResource.." it returns the URL of the LWJGL libraries rather than my own. Is there a way to get around this?